# Language neutral "Dynamic Connector" in Visio-vba

Tags: vba, visio

I have a VBA macro that draws *dynamic Connectors*. The *connector master* is instiantated like this:

```
dim flowChartStencils as visio.document
set flowChartStencils = documents.openEx(templatePath, 0)

dim connectorMaster as visio.master
set connectorMaster = flowChartStencils.masters(dynamicConnectorName)
```

The problem I am facing is that both the `templatePath` and the `dynamicConnectorName` seems to be dependant on the language of the visio installation. So, further up in the code, I have a:

```
' const templatePath = "C:\Programme\Microsoft Office\Visio10\1031\Solutions\Flowchart\Basic Flowchart Shapes (US units).vss"
  const templatePath = "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Visio10\1031\Lösungen\Flussdiagramm\Grundlegende Flussdiagramm-Shapes.VSS"
```

and a

```
' const dynamicConnectorName = "Dynamic Connector"
  const dynamicConnectorName = "Dynamischer Verbinder"
```

both of which i comment and un-comment according to the language of the installation.

Since I want to port the vba code to different installations, I was wondering if there is an easier way or even what the easiest way is to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
If Application.Language = "English" Then
    const dynamicConnectorName = "Dynamic Connector"
Elseif Application.Language = "German" Then
    const dynamicConnectorName = "Dynamischer Verbinder"
End If
```

Comment: So, basically, that's how Microsoft intended it to be?